# if cell contains .com or .co.uk - if statement in excel / google spreadsheets

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets

Ive got a list of urls, Im  trying to check if for each cell the the url contains `.com OR .co.uk` and if it does put the text TRUE into the result cell, this way i can filter the result column to find all the cells that contain .com or .co.uk as the top level domain of the url.

At the moment im trying to use

`=IF(D2=".com","TRUE", "FALSE")`

The issue Im having is to do with the first argument to check if the url contains `.com OR .co.uk`, at the moment its just checking if the whole `url == .com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FIND`:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(".com",A1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(".co.uk",A1)))
```

[image]

Use `ISNUMBER` to swallow any #VALUE! errors.

Note that `FIND` does a case-sensitive search.  For a case-insensitive search, use `SEARCH` instead.

Comment: An alternative way of doing this would be to use regexmatch. Something like: =ArrayFormula(regexmatch(A2:A12, "(com|co.uk)")) where A2:A12 is the range to be checked.

Comment: @user3889423, good point, that would work in Google Spreadsheet.  But `FIND` should work in both applications.

Comment: I don't use excel myself, that's probably why I overlooked the word 'excel' in the title. ;-) I also don't know how regexmatch works in excel. But.. good point ! and thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @user3889423, unfortunately, Excel doesn't have a built-in function for doing regular expressions.  Lots of VBA code would become unnecessary if it did.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use regexextract with an or "|" to give it both variations:

```
=if(isna(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\.com|\.co\.uk")),,true)
```